# Is there a way to keep a test.Bat file open and run the rest of the code?

Tags: java, maven, batch-file, runtime.exec, seq

I have this code below - where the batch file is executed but the program wont execute the rest of the code rather it stay in the batch file itself.
What I want to achieve is to have this BATCH file running while the rest of the code executes.

```
public class CmdJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c call README.bat");
        
        String s;
        System.out.println(p.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
//code reaches and stops at this line as the batch file need to be forcefully closed
        }
        System.out.print("Need to reach this code");
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Please [edit] your question, to remove the image, and replace it with thre actual text content, formatted correctly into code boxes. Nobody is going to zoom around your image and copy the content character by character into files in order to begin to assist you.

Comment: `cmd /c start README.bat`?

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters.